# Is V8 engine inside of the JavaScript runtime or is JavaScript Runtime inside of the V8? Are they both the same?

Tags: javascript, runtime, v8

The confusion started after i read an article on **the medium** which says
**Also in the runtime environment is a JavaScript Engine that parses the code. Each browser has its own version of a JS engine. Chrome uses what it calls its V8 JS Engine and that is what we will analyze now.**

whereas the **Node document** says
**V8 provides the runtime environment in which JavaScript executes. **

Medium Article : https://olinations.medium.com/the-javascript-runtime-environment-d58fa2e60dd0
Node JS: https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-v8-javascript-engine

Answer (score 1):

V8 is a JavaScript engine: it can execute JavaScript code.

This, together with a set of basic libraries and APIs makes up the JavaScript runtime environment.

Node.js is one JavaScript runtime environment that uses V8 and provides a set of APIs focused around building server-side JavaScript applications.

Google Chrome provides a different JavaScript runtime environment built on top of V8 by providing a *different* set of libraries and APIs to allow building web applications.

Comment: So are these independent of each other but working together?

Comment: Not really independent. A runtime environment needs some engine and the actual library implementation is usually tightly coupled to the chose engine (i.e. you can't just arbitrarily swap out JS engines, that's usually an involved process). But a single engine can easily be used in different runtime environment (as demonstrated by V8).

Comment: As a conclusion can we say that the addition of some extra features to the JavaScript engine makes up the runtime environment ?